# How to select current element in CKEditor..?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I want to select current(cursor position) element in CKEditor using java script.

When right click event happens i have to select an element where i am right clicking.

Comment: What do you mean by "current (cursor position) element"?

Comment: i am using context menu item. when an context menu button clicked i have to select that element where the click happens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the solution you're looking for:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1,
    sel = editor.getSelection();

sel.selectElement(sel.getStartElement());
```